# How to display top 5 values in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database query that displays students and their average rating in descending order.
Here is the query snippet:

[image]

And I only want to get the 5 best performing students. Moreover, it is desirable in the least expensive way, because this request will be performed repeatedly

Comment: add limit 5 at the end of query

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSql 13+ then use `FETCH FIRST`

```
SELECT name, 
           AVG(score) as avg_score
FROM students
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY avg_score DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS WITH TIES
```

If you have 6 names with the same maximum average score then `WITH TIES` will return all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT to set how many rows you want back.

```
SELECT name, AVG(score) as average_rating from students
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY average_rating DESC
LIMIT 5;
```